# How to plot just one label per ax.plot, when the argument of ax.plot is a list?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Having the following line in my plot code

```
ax.plot(x, pdf_individual, '--k', label = "single Gaussians")
```

, with `pdf_individual` being a list of lists, results in this picture:

[image]

Is there a way to just have "single Gaussians" once in the labels, instead of 6 times, which is the amount of single Gaussians for the Gaussian Mixture Model?

This is the whole post with the suggested solution

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 600

test_input =  input_list # THIS IS A 1D LIST with a few hundred items
X = np.asarray(test_input).reshape(-1,1)

N = np.arange(1, 11)
models = [None for i in range(len(N))]
for i in range(len(N)):
    models[i] = GaussianMixture(N[i]).fit(X)

# compute the AIC and the BIC
AIC = [m.aic(X) for m in models]
BIC = [m.bic(X) for m in models]



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9,
                    bottom=0.21, top=0.9, wspace=0.3)



ax = fig.add_subplot(131)
M_best = models[np.argmin(AIC)]
comp_count = str(M_best)
x = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 100)
logprob = M_best.score_samples(x.reshape(-1, 1))
responsibilities = M_best.predict_proba(x.reshape(-1, 1))
pdf = np.exp(logprob)
pdf_individual = responsibilities * pdf[:, np.newaxis]

                        
left, width = .245, .5
bottom, height = .4, .5
right = left + width
top = bottom + height
plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=-45, ha="left" )
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
ax.hist(X, 30, density=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.4, label="Data")
ax.plot(x, pdf, '-k', color = "red", label='GMM')
for i, pdf_individual in enumerate(pdf_individual):
    ax.plot(x, pdf_individual, '--k', label = "single Gaussians" if i == 0 else "")
#for pdf in pdf_individual[1:]: ax.plot(x, pdf, '--k')
ax.text(right, top, "Anzahl Komponenten: " + comp_count[-2],
        horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='bottom',
        transform=ax.transAxes)

ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$p(x)$')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

It results in this error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (6,)
```

EDIT:

Putting

```
pdf_individual = np.transpose(pdf_individual)
```

makes the code above work

Comment: I normally do it like this: `ax.plot(x, pdf_individual[0], '--k', label = "single Gaussians")` and then `for pdf in pdf_individual[1:]: ax.plot(x, pdf, '--k')`. It's a lot of boilerplate but it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate items in legend in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385639/duplicate-items-in-legend-in-matplotlib) In essence, what ForceBru does in one line: `[ax.plot(x, y, '--k', label = "single Gaussians" if not i else "") for i, y in enumerate(pdf_individual)]`

Comment: @ForceBru I get this error:
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (7,)
This error makes sense to me, i just wonder why the whole code worked. Since len of the pdf_individual is 100, so its 100 lists with 6 values. I would have expected to have 6 lists with 100 values instead actually

Comment: @Mr.T i get the same error unfortunately..

Comment: @Stefan44, I've come across that issue before - [there's an explanation somewhere in the `plot` source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71213425/what-is-being-plotted-by-plt-plot-with-a-tuple-argument/71216046#71216046). In the first case, `matplotlib` figures it out but in the second you are explicitly describing how to iterate. Can you make `pdf_individual` a numpy array and transpose it?

Comment: Obviously, as it is the same approach. The error message, output, and your description of the data do not match. If you want  help, you should provide [a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i will update the post, one second

Comment: i don't really know how to reduce the code so that it remains complete enough for the issue, since i don't really get where the transformation of the lists happens as I got most of the code from here: http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter4/fig_GMM_1D.html

However, any simple Input list should give you the same results

Comment: @ramzeek transposing worked!